# Ruby, MySQL: Connection pool that is outside of the rails framework?

Tags: mysql, ruby, connection-pooling

Is there a ruby gem or such for MySQL connection pooling that isn't part of rails? I simply have a ruby script (again, I don't do anything with rails).

Comment: Do you use ActiveRecord? If not, what do you use?

Comment: just the regular MySQL db driver gems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Seamless Database Pool](http://github.com/bdurand/seamless_database_pool) is supposed to work "with any ActiveRecord application", and ActiveRecord is easy to use without Rails. I've used ActiveRecord in a plain Ruby app, and it was just a matter of configuring the logger and the database connection, something like

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = App.logger
dbconfig = YAML::load(File.open("#{APP_ROOT}/config/database.yml"))
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(dbconfig[ENV["APP_ENV"]])
```

I haven't used Seamless Database Pool outside of Rails, but I couldn't find any connection poolers aimed at plain Ruby apps after a quick search so it might be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JRuby (with ActiveRecord and JDBC adapter) you can configure a J2EE container to handle DB connection pool and pass the pool in database.yml via jndi similar to [here (example with oracle)](http://syntatic.wordpress.com/2008/08/20/connection-pooling-for-rails-on-jruby-using-jndi-and-jdbc/).

Also, [some slides for MYSQL pools via ActiveRecord](http://www.slideshare.net/Naoto.Takai/jruby-on-rails-and-thread-safety-presentation)

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => 'mysql',
  :username => 'root',
  :password => '123456',
  :database => 'database',
  :pool => 5 # <- CONN POOL
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could wrap the [connection_pool gem](http://rubydoc.info/gems/connection_pool/0.9.2/frames) around a couple single connections.

Examples from the doc (redis):

> Example usage with block (faster):
>
> ```
> @pool = ConnectionPool.new { Redis.new }
>
> @pool.with do |redis|
>   redis.lpop('my-list') if redis.llen('my-list') > 0
> end
> ```
>
> Example usage replacing an existing connection (slower):
>
> ```
> $redis = ConnectionPool.wrap { Redis.new }
>
> def do_work
>   $redis.lpop('my-list') if $redis.llen('my-list') > 0
> end
> ```